# PHP With Youtube XML API

Tags: php, xml, youtube

My problem is regarding using PHP to access data from a YouTube XML feed. The truncated feed is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007">
   <id>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/AaiKcIfHEzUZl34U980sNA</id>
   <yt:firstName>wahbanana</yt:firstName>
   <yt:googlePlusUserId>118419787126790739507</yt:googlePlusUserId>
   <yt:location>SG</yt:location>
   <yt:statistics lastWebAccess="1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z" subscriberCount="353936" videoWatchCount="0" viewCount="0" totalUploadViews="40288085" />
   <media:thumbnail url="http://yt3.ggpht.com/-ukikCGaaWTw/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/zmPZoDtJEK0/s88-c-k-no/photo.jpg" />
   <yt:username>wahbanana</yt:username>
</entry>
```

I wrote a function to get subscribeCount iinside yt:statistics:

```
$url = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/'.$yt_username;
$xml = file_get_contents($url);
$feed = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$ns=$feed->getNameSpaces(true);

$yt = $entry->children($ns['yt']);
$yt_statistics = $yt->statistics->attributes();
$yt_subscribers = $yt_statistics['subscriberCount'];
```

But it returns this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function children() on a non-object in /home/digitali/public_html/wp-content/plugins/OCG-socialintegration/ocg_si.php on line 111
```

Can someone point out to me what is wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you want `$yt = $feed->children($ns['yt']);`. `$entry` is not defined anywhere in the script.

Comment: Do not read the namespace from the XML using its prefix (alias) in the document. The prefix is not the identifier - the namespace is. Just write the namespace `http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007` in a constant/variable in your source and use it.

Comment: who is so mean to down vote this? explain.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you dont have `$entry`, change to:

```
$feed = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$ns = $feed->getNamespaces(true);
$yt = $feed->children($ns['yt']);
.....
```